# Unrar the files with the name of the rar files

Tags: python, unrar

I have folder with 4 rar (zipped) files.

[screenshot #1: rar files and names](https://ibb.co/0J9TKwh)

This is the python code to unrar them:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, zipfile, pyunpack, sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

basis_folder = askdirectory(title='Select Folder')
    
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basis_folder):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".rar") :
            print('RAR:'+os.path.join(root,filename))
        elif filename.endswith(".zip"):
            print('ZIP:'+os.path.join(root,filename))
        name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
        if filename.endswith(".rar") or filename.endswith(".zip"):
            try:
                arch = pyunpack.Archive(os.path.join(root,filename))
                # os.mkdir(name)
                arch.extractall(directory=root)
                os.remove(os.path.join(root,filename))
            except Exception as e:
                print("ERROR: BAD ARCHIVE "+os.path.join(root,filename))
                print(e)
                try:
                    # os.path.join(root,filename)os.remove(filename)
                    pass
                except OSError as e: # this would be "except OSError, e:" before Python 2.6
                    if e.errno != errno.ENOENT: # errno.ENOENT = no such file or directory
                        raise # re-raise exception if a different error occured
                    sys.exit()
os._exit(0)
```

After unrar process, the code deletes the rar files and extract the files inside rar files. I want the rename of the files as file1 from rarfile1, file2 from rarfile1, file3 from rarfile1, file1 from rarfile2, so on...

This is the result I want:

[[screenshot #2: unrar files and their new names]](https://ibb.co/TL8pySP)

Answer (score 1):

```
/root/
    - example1.rar
    - example2.rar
```

One way to achieve this would be to do these steps,there would definitely be a better way I believe though:

1. Temporarily create a directory with the same name as your rar file. (A directoty /root/example1/ for /root/example1.rar file
2. Move the Rar file  to the temporary directory
   /root/example1/example1.rar
3. Extract all files from example1.rar file to example1 directory

```
    /root/
         example1/
         file1.ext
         file2.ext
         example1.rar
```

4. Delete the rar file

```
 /root/    
      example1/
      file1.ext
      file2.ext
```

4. Rename all files in example1 directory to example1_file1.ext

```
    /root/
       /example1/
               example1_file1.ext
               example1_file2.ext
```

5. Move all files to /root/

```
        /root/
               /example1/
               example1_file1.ext
               example1_file2.ext
```

6. Delete /example1/ directory :

```
        /root/
               example1_file1.ext
               example1_file2.ext
```

7. Loop through all Rars this way. End result :

   ```
    /root/
           example1_file1.ext
           example1_file2.ext
           example2_file1.ext
           example2_file2.ext
   ```

I have not run and validated the code - but your code will get modified along below lines :

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basis_folder):
for filename in files:
    if filename.endswith(".rar"):
        print('RAR:' + os.path.join(root, filename))
    elif filename.endswith(".zip"):
        print('ZIP:' + os.path.join(root, filename))
    name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
    if filename.endswith(".rar") or filename.endswith(".zip"):
        try:
            # root/yourfile.rar
            curr_file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            # root/yourfile/
            new_file_dir = curr_file_path.split('.')[0]
            # root/yourfile/yourfile.rar
            new_file_path = os.path.join(new_file_dir, filename)
            os.mkdir(new_file_dir)
            os.replace(curr_file_path, new_file_path)
            arch = pyunpack.Archive(new_file_path)
            # extract files to root/yourfile
            arch.extractall(directory=new_file_dir)
            # Remove the Rar file
            os.remove(new_file_path)
            files_in_curr = [f for f in os.listdir(new_file_dir) if os.path.isfile(f)]
            for file in files_in_curr:
                new_name = os.path.join(new_file_dir, filename.split('.')[0] + '_' + file)
                # Rename file from root/yourfile/file1.ext to root/yourfile/yourfile_file1.ext
                os.rename(os.path.join(new_file_dir, file), new_name)
                # move file from root/yourfile/yourfile_file1.ext to root/yourfile_file1.ext
                os.replace(os.path.join(new_file_dir, new_name), os.path.join(root, new_name))
            # Remove the temporary empty directory
            os.rmdir(new_file_dir)

        except Exception as e:
            print("ERROR: BAD ARCHIVE " + os.path.join(root, filename))
            print(e)
            try:
                # os.path.join(root,filename)os.remove(filename)
                pass
            except OSError as e:  # this would be "except OSError, e:" before Python 2.6
                if e.errno != errno.ENOENT:  # errno.ENOENT = no such file or directory
                    raise  # re-raise exception if a different error occured
                sys.exit()
  os._exit(0)
```

Comment: This is a better solution. Thank you, Deepak!